# Kotlin: zip two lists with index

Tags: kotlin, syntax

Is there a way to [zip](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/zip.html#zip) two lists in Kotlin, knowing current index in the transform lambda?

Something like this?

```
val list1 = listOf("a", "b", "c")
val list2 = listOf("x", "y", "z")
val joined = list1.zipWithIndex(list2){ a,b,i -> listOf(a,b,c)}

print(joined) // [[a, x, 0], [b, y, 1], [c, z, 2]]
```

Comment: You could try [`withIndex()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/with-index.html)?

Comment: `list1.zip(list2).withIndex().map { (i, pair) -> listOf(pair.first, pair.second, i) }` But you end up with a `List<Any>` which is not very useful.

Comment: Thanks to both of you :) So far I have this: `val joined = list1.zip(list2).mapIndexed { index, zipped -> zipped.toList() + index }`, but I wonder if there is any nicer solution.

Comment: Instead of a list inside, you could use a Triple `list1.zip(list2).withIndex().map { (i, pair) -> Triple(pair.first, pair.second, i) }`. You would retain the types of the lists and index. (Or use a custom (data) class instead of triple to have more meaningful names and avoid boxing)

Comment: Thanks, this probably the best approach when one needs to store the combined list and use it elsewhere. That is actually not my case now, but it may become handy in future. It can be also used with the solution provided in the answer by broot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have only 2 lists, then the closest you can get is probably by using `withIndex()` and then destructuring inside the lambda passed to `zip()`:

```kotlin
list1.withIndex().zip(list2) { (i, a), b -> listOf(i, a, b) }
```

Comparing to the solution in the comment, this may be a little more confusing as we first add index and then the second list, but this way we don't need `map()` and as we receive 2 arguments in the lambda we can destructure them fully.